# Почему приложение тормозит при работе с Canvas?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, почему может подтармаживать?

Есть ArrayList в котором храню то, что нужно рисовать

```
public ArrayList<touchXYA> mPointList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Есть метод добавления  объектов (при касаниии экрана) в этот ArrayList

```
synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
            mPointList.add(new touchXYA(posX, posY, StartProgress, touchRadius));
}
```

Рисую все в потоке:

```
        public void run() {
            this.run = true;
            Canvas c = null;
            while (run) {


                try {
                    c = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (this.surfaceHolder) {
                        doDraw(c);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        this.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(settings_pause);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
           }
   }

    private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Drawing back image and fog on it
        try {
            backPaint.setAlpha(255);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, backPaint);
            fogPaint.setAlpha(120);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, fogPaint);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Exception : ", e.toString());
        }


        // Drawing mPointList touches
        for (touchXYA tempPoint : mPointList) {

            double percentOfProgress = tempPoint.progress / StartProgress;
            Log.v("percentOfProgress: ", Double.toString(percentOfProgress));

            backPaint.setAlpha(255);
            double tempRadius = tempPoint.radius;
            tempRadius = 0.5 * (tempRadius + tempRadius * Math.sqrt(percentOfProgress));
            canvas.drawCircle(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y, (float) tempRadius, backPaint);
            fogPaint.setAlpha((int) (settings_StartTouchAlpha + (1 - percentOfProgress) * settings_EndTouchAlpha));
            canvas.drawCircle(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y, (float) tempRadius, fogPaint);
}
}
```

Comment: А зачем делать `this.run = true;` и `while (run) `? У потока есть специальная проверка `isInterrupted()`. Когда нужно, чтобы поток остановился, нужно вызвать его метод `interrupt()`, а внутри проверку делать `while(!isInterrupted())`.

Comment: По этому коду ничего не сказать, мало ли что у вас там в doDraw() написано.

Comment: Павел, спасибо за замечание, подумаю над ним, но не думаю что тормоза из-за этого.

Comment: Евгений, добавил в вопрос doDraw метод.Приложение делаю по примеру: http://dajver.blogspot.com/2012/02/android.html

Comment: Может дело в `sleep(settings_pause)` ?.. зачем здесь используется пауза?

Comment: Пауза для того, чтобы регулировать частоту перерисовки 'Canvas'. Т.к. нет необходимости перерисовывать его постоянно.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что проблема либо в том, что когда я делаю lockCanvas, то перестают обрабатываться касания, либо они не добавляются в arraylist т.к. он в блоке synchronized

Comment: У меня слишком мало информации, чтобы что либо утверждать, но не исключаю проблему в архитектуре. Я бы вместо `sleep(settings_pause)` сделал `wait` до тех пор, пока не поступят новые данные для рисования (например: касание к экрану). И при необходимости будил бы поток (для рисования на канвасе).

Comment: Увеличил 'setting_pause' до 3х секунд - касания не теряются. Убрал вообще - касания теряются во время отрисовки (когда 'doDraw' работает). Сейчас буду что то с этим делать. Для начала определю обрабатывает ли android касания в момент когда я рисую, если да, то буду менять arraylist на потокобезопасный